# \docsvlist and nested functions: unwanted large spaces

Tags: etoolbox

I would like to iterate through a comma separated list to translate some words. I already found how to do so using `\docsvlist` from the `etoolbox` package. However, there is a large space printed before the first word and between the words when there should only be a "normal" space after the printed comma. I think the problem comes from the nesting of the `\ifstrequal` commands used for the translation.

Below is a MWE including an example calling all the possible translations and another example calling only the first translation to show the impact of the nesting.

How can I avoid these additional spaces?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
    
    \newcommand\TranslateAnimal[1]{
        \ifstrequal{#1}{Cat}{Chat}{
            \ifstrequal{#1}{Dog}{Chien}{
                \ifstrequal{#1}{Mouse}{Souris}{
                    \ifstrequal{#1}{Bird}{Oiseau}{
                        \ifstrequal{#1}{Horse}{Cheval}{
                            #1 % If there is no known translation
        }}}}}
    }

    \newcommand{\TranslateAnimalList}[2][,]{
        \def\nextitem{\def\nextitem{#1}}% Separator
        \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\nextitem\TranslateAnimal{##1}} % How to process each item
        \docsvlist{#2}% Process list
    }

    There are additional large spaces before the first word and after words: \TranslateAnimalList{Cat,Bird,Dog,Horse,Mouse,Seal,Donkey}
    
    Compare with: \TranslateAnimalList{Cat,Cat,Cat,Cat,Cat,Cat,Cat} where there is only a large space before the first word

\end{document}
```

Comment: every end of line is a space and the space after #1 is a space so your `\TranslateAnimal` has 8 spaces, use `%` at ends of lines to comment them out, and remove the space after`#1`

Comment: Thank you! I was always wondering why people where commenting end of lines...

Comment: your second macro adds two more

Comment: See [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines? (Why is my macro creating extra space?)](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the differences and look at [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines? (Why is my macro creating extra space?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand\TranslateAnimal[1]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{Cat}{Chat}{%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{Dog}{Chien}{%
      \ifstrequal{#1}{Mouse}{Souris}{%
        \ifstrequal{#1}{Bird}{Oiseau}{%
          \ifstrequal{#1}{Horse}{Cheval}{%
            #1% If there is no known translation
  }}}}}%
}

\newcommand{\TranslateAnimalList}[2][, ]{%
  \def\nextitem{\def\nextitem{#1}}% Separator
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\nextitem\TranslateAnimal{##1}}% How to process each item
  \docsvlist{#2}% Process list
}

\begin{document}
    
The list is \TranslateAnimalList{Cat,Bird,Dog,Horse,Mouse,Seal,Donkey}.

Compare with \TranslateAnimalList{Cat,Cat,Cat,Cat,Cat,Cat,Cat}.

\end{document}
```

You can possibly appreciate a different implementation with `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed with LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\TranslateAnimal}{m}
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {Cat}{Chat}
    {Dog}{Chien}
    {Mouse}{Souris}
    {Bird}{Oiseau}
    {Horse}{Cheval}
   }
   { #1 } % no known translation
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\TranslateAnimalList}{O{,~}m}
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \TranslateAnimal { ##1 } }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    
The list is \TranslateAnimalList{Cat,Bird,Dog,Horse,Mouse,Seal,Donkey}.

Compare with \TranslateAnimalList{Cat,Cat,Cat,Cat,Cat,Cat,Cat}.

\end{document}
```

[image]